# Select a specific number of rows (below the header row) based on value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to select a specific number of cells in Sheet3 based on the count available in cell Z1 in Sheet2. The below code is somewhat of help, but not completely. The data in Sheet3 is a filtered range and I'd like to select only the visible cells (based on the count provided in Z1) below the header column in Sheet 3. Thanks in advance!

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:X" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Z1").Value).Select
```

Comment: Did you try `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:X" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Z1").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`?

Comment: Hi AntiDrondert, Thank you for your response! The code you gave selects the visible cells (and that's of great help). But, it selects the header row too. I'd like the rows to be selected below the header row in Sheet 3 based on the count in Z1.

Comment: Change `A1` into `A2` , assuming your header is only 1 row

Comment: Hi Luuklag, Thanks for your help! When I change A1 to A2, only the row A2 gets selected. Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your headers take one row. Change `HeaderRows` accordingly.Private

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myRange As Range, HeaderRows As Long
    Dim newRange As Range, myArea As Range
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:X" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Z1").Value)
    'Change number of rows accordingly
    HeaderRows = 1
    With myRange
        Set myRange = .Offset(HeaderRows, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - HeaderRows, _
                                      .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    'Loop through each visible area
    Set newRange = myRange.Areas(1)
    For Each myArea In myRange.Areas
        'Add area to a range
        Set newRange = Application.Union(myArea, newRange)
    Next
    'Select new range
    newRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi AntiDrondert! Thanks again for your help! The updated code only selects the first row below the header row no matter whatever value is in Z1. I followed your code exactly and I'm not sure what I missed.

Comment: Hi AntiDrondert! This time it throws a 1004 error [in the line  Set myRange = .Offset(HeaderRows, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - HeaderRows, _
                                      .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ]  saying that no cells were found. But there is data in Sheet 3 as well as Z1. Thanks again for helping me with this!

Comment: @Pret It means there are no visible cells in specified region. Check the region you're checking with `.Address` property.

Comment: I did check, @AntiDrondert! There are visible cells! :/